# Yii: jQuery with Bootstrap conflict issue in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am developing a website in Yii I am facing a problem in registerScriptFile

I have following Scripts included in my View.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('font-awesome');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('angular');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/angular/controllers/ListController.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/angular/controllers/pagination.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/angular/filters/filters.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/jquery.tools.min.js');
//Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js');

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js');

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js');

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/listView.js');
```

You can see jquery-ui.js is commented, when it is commented the tooltips start working but the dialog that I created is not working and all the dialog items displayed on the main screen & most of the thing not working correctly, & when I uncomment the save jquery-ui.js the tooltips are not working but the dialog start working accurately and all other things works correctly, So I need both tooltips and dialogs & other items working,

I use this to display tooltips

```
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

I think the problem is with jQuery & bootstrap conflect...
I also use `$.noConflict(); $.noConflict(true);` but not working

Please help how I order these files so that I get the working of every thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download custom jquery-ui.js without selecting tooltip and manually import it to your project because bootstrap and jquery-ui.js both have tooltip included in it, so its conflicting with tooltip, so you should eliminate tooltip from one of them, hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thankyou very much it'll make some sense to me. I do this now.